# How can I scroll a Clutter.ScrollActor with a scrollbar?

Tags: gtk, scrollbar, gnome, vala, clutter

I have a a [`GtkClutter.Embed`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-gtk-0.10/GtkClutter.Embed) that holds a complete graph of clutter actors. The most important actor is `container_actor` that holds a variable number of actors (laid out with a `FlowLayout`) that may overflow the height allocated to the parent Embed.

At some point, the `container_actor` *takes the stage* and be the only actor displayed (along with its children).

At this point I would like to be able to scroll through the content of `container_actor`.

Making my Embed implementing [`Gtk.Scrollable`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Scrollable) gives the ability to have a scrollbar. Also I've noticed that Clutter proposes a [`Clutter.ScrollActor`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.ScrollActor).

**Is using those two classes the recommended way to go?**

Or do I need to use implement Gtk.Scrollable and move my `container_actor` manually on `vadjustment.value_changed` ?

> **edit**: [here's a sample in c](https://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter/tree/examples/scroll-actor.c?id=60dbeb9425f51fc602ba2fe89b2a968ef4b527ed) for `ScrollActor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClutterScrollActor` does not know anything about `GtkScrollable` or `GtkAdjustment`, so you will have to implement scrolling manually. It's not necessary to implement `GtkScrollable` — you just need a `GtkScrollbar` widget, a `GtkAdjustment` and some code that connects to the `GtkAdjustment::value-changed` signal to determine the point to which you wish to scroll the contents of the `ClutterScrollActor`.